# NSView touchesMovedWithEvent in subview is pausing an SKScene with built-in trackpad, but not magic trackpad?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, trackpad

I have a custom NSView subclass that is being used as the subview in my project https://github.com/torchie/TrackKit. It detects NSTouches and collects physical data on them, and then draws those things in the verbose-mode method of its drawRect. Meanwhile, the SpriteKit scene renders what it renders.

However, when I *move* a finger on the built-in trackpad, **all rendering in the SpriteKit view is paused until the touch is once-again stationary.** On the Magic Trackpad, there is a framerate drop, but the rendering doesn't stop completely. In both cases, the subview TKDetectorView continues to render the touch points.

the touchesMoved method in question:

```
-(void)touchesMovedWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    for(NSTouch* touch in [event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseAny inView:self]) {
        [touch_identities setObject:touch forKey:[touch identity]];
    }
    [self phys_record];

    if(![self needsDisplay]) {
        [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    }   
}
```

The data from a breakpoint on the verbose-mode function wherein I simultaneously touched the built-in trackpad (#0) and Magic Trackpad (#1):

```
touch_identities    __NSDictionaryM *   2 key/value pairs   0x0000608000055bd0
    [0] (null)  (no summary) : (no summary) 
        key NSConcreteValue *   0x600000054b80  0x0000600000054b80
        value   NSTouch *   0x6000000b2480  0x00006000000b2480
        NSObject    NSObject        
        _index  NSInteger   10  10
        _identity   NSConcreteValue *   0x600000054b80  0x0000600000054b80
        _phase  NSTouchPhase    2   2
        _normalizedPosition NSPoint (x=0.4923553466796875, y=0.4602508544921875)    
            x   CGFloat 0.4923553466796875  0.4923553466796875
            y   CGFloat 0.4602508544921875  0.4602508544921875
        _privateFlags   NSInteger   0   0
        _view   TKDetectorView *    0x6000001ff900  0x00006000001ff900
        _device NSObject *  0x600000013300  0x0000600000013300
        _deviceSize NSSize  (width=368.50393709999997, height=311.81102370000002)   
        previous_positions  NSMutableArray *    nil 0x0000000000000000
        _isResting  BOOL    YES '\xad'
[1] (null)  (no summary) : (no summary) 
    key NSConcreteValue *   0x60800005ea50  0x000060800005ea50
    value   NSTouch *   0x6080000b3740  0x00006080000b3740
        NSObject    NSObject        
        _index  NSInteger   1   1
        _identity   NSConcreteValue *   0x60800005ea50  0x000060800005ea50
        _phase  NSTouchPhase    2   2
        _normalizedPosition NSPoint (x=0.7928314208984375, y=0.3984222412109375)    
        _privateFlags   NSInteger   0   0
        _view   TKDetectorView *    0x6000001ff900  0x00006000001ff900
        _device NSObject *  0x600000014d70  0x0000600000014d70
        _deviceSize NSSize  (width=297.63779534999998, height=215.43307092000001)   
        previous_positions  NSMutableArray *    nil 0x0000000000000000
        _isResting  BOOL    YES '\xad'
```

I thought it could be the result of the SpriteKit rendering thread being interrupted by the constant modification of the array of positions when a finger is moving, but that wouldn't explain why it's happening only on the built-in trackpad of a MacBook Air and not an external Magic Trackpad. I could find no relevant difference between the interpretation of a touchesMoved between the devices.

Answer (score 0):

Original hypothesis: The polling rate of the built-in trackpad is significantly higher than the magic trackpad for touchesMoved events, causing a higher number of drawRects and interrupting the SpriteKit view's drawing thread.

Failed — incrementing a counter for both the number of touchesMovedWithEvent calls and the number of drawRect calls from setNeedsDisplay showed no notable difference in quantity between the built-in and the Magic Trackpad in the same time period.

Solution:

touchesMovedWithEvent called setNeedsDisplay for the custom view at the end of the method.

**Eliminating setNeedsDisplay calls in touchesMovedWithEvent and instead calling the custom view's setNeedsDisplay in the SpriteKit scene's update method, thereby operating on that subview "from above" fixed the issue.**

TKMyScene:

```
-(void)update {
    [detector setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

instead of TKDetectorView

```
-(void)touchesMovedWithEvent {
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```